# Surname on One Passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I have dual nationality, but on my second passport, my Surname was been spelt correctly at the top portion of the Bio-data page (AFRANI) but was wrongly spelt at  the scannable portion(AFRIAN) of the same page. Will this cause any issue.

Comment: Did you contact the passport office (or wherever you had to apply) as this is clearly a mistake and may be a problem?

Comment: yes and they said they will get back to me, but am yet to hear from them.

Comment: I personally would not accept this passport and hand it back to them. (But where I live you go to your town house to apply for and collect your passport.)

Comment: Issues with what? Are you travelling somewhere? Which passport will you be using?

Comment: My surname has been spelt correctly at the top portion, but as the lower portion with the sign << >>, the position of an alphabet has been misplaced.

Comment: Ghanaman, is that a Ghana passport?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify.  Putting on hold for now.